# Firebase App crashing on startup swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a ios app connected to my firebase, in which I have a class where I have defined all the links to firebase-database.

AppDelegate.swift contains aa `init()` method so, Firebase is the first one to be initialized.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    FirebaseApp.configure()

}
```

Firebase Dataservice where all DB paths are defined.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

let DB_URL: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
let ST_URL: StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

class FBDataservice {
//... other code
}
```

Now as soon as I Launch the app, I get an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This error is made on the uid definition in dataservice class.

Now, As far as I understand, This is because the uid may be initialized even when there is no user.

I am out of Ideas on how to implement this. I have many references to uid in my entire project. What is the most apt way to perform this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use the `observeAuthEventWithBlock`.

> To listen for changes in the authentication state, attach an event
>   observer with observeAuthEventWithBlock. If there is no user currently
>   authenticated, authData will be nil.

You implement it like this according to the [reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication):

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock({ authData in
    if authData != nil {
        // user authenticated
        println(authData)
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
    }
})
```

Comment: should I be implementing this with the `Firebase.config` in appDelegate. if not, where is this to be put?

Comment: @AakashDave, monitor this in your `viewController`.

Comment: I had made a small error. but, thanks to you, you helped me point out a big bug in my code. Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: Np glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure where you are initializing your code. 
Possible solutions:

1. Use guard statement `guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}`
2. Try putting this code in a function that will return an optional string.
3. If you are trying to check if the user exists before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, make an if else statement or guard statement like the one above. `if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil`
4. If you are using Cocoapods, try with `pod update`
5. If these are not working, try reinstalling the pod.
6. Call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in appDelegate and return true.